# How to programmatically delete objects stored in Oracle Object Storage?

Tags: oracle-cloud-shell

How to programmatically delete objects stored in Oracle Object Storage?

DELETE /filename returns with 404-Notfound.

I could create files using pre authenticated URL (to a folder) in Oracle Object Storage . These files are created using PUT /filename API.

I am currently using 'Lifecycle Policy Rules', however I need ability to delete as soon as i am done.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out objects cannot be deleted using Pre Authenticated Request. I ended up using ‘Lifecycle Policy Rules’ to purge files.